# Cassandra C# Driver returns first 5000 rows only

Tags: cassandra, datastax-csharp-driver

I am trying to get all the records form Cassandra table but getting 5 thousand rows only. Is there any way to get all the result form a table?

Below are the version details:
It is the driver version 3.11.0
My server version is [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Below is my code

```
//Create a cluster instance using 3 cassandra nodes.
var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
.AddContactPoints("xx.xx.xx.xx")
 .Build();
var session = cluster.Connect("keyspace");
var rs = session.Execute("select * from table ALLOW FILTERING");
ini i=0;
 foreach (var row in rs)
 {
    i++;
}
```

The value of `i` is always 5000. I tried to implement paging to get all the data but was not able to do so.

```
 while (!rs.IsFullyFetched)
 {
     rs.FetchMoreResults();
     foreach (var row in rs)
     {
         i++;
     }
 }
```

I'm still getting the same result

Also trying to follow the URL
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.13/features/paging/
but that too is not working because I am not using any filter.
But when I tried to introduce a filter the result is 0 rows.

```
    var ps = session.Prepare("select * from table where state = ? ALLOW FILTERING");
    //// Set the page size at statement level.
    var statement = ps.Bind("xyz").SetPageSize(1000);
    var rs = session.Execute(statement);
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var row in rs)
    {
       i++;
    }
```

There are record for the particular state but not getting any data. The number of records is zero.
Earlier I had issue too with the driver version 
[Query Cassandra form C# no result is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575592/query-cassandra-form-c-sharp-no-result-is-shown/63591372#63591372)

Comment: did you trying specifying a `LIMIT` greater then 5000 in your query? for instance `select * from table LIMIT 50000 ALLOW FILTERING`. ref [cql 3.x doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html) .. note: *Controlling the number of rows returned using PER PARTITION LIMIT* section

Comment: in regards to "Also trying [paging] but that too is not working because I am not using any filter".. I don't understand your comment of not using any filter; your query specifies ALLOW FILTERS, and the LINQ expression should itself build\generate the query command with the filter if you express it.  but that may beside the point... my first question is, does the data in your table have with a column called state that has 'xyz'? second, did you try `.SetAutoPage(false)` like the snippet says? also, to avoid querying column unnecessarily try  `... table 1 = ?` and `ps.Bind(1)`

Comment: @BrettCaswell the paging is not working when I set the `statement.SetAutoPage(false);statement.SetPageSize(1000);` I am not getting data more than 1000. I have tried to see the value of  `Console.WriteLine(rs.IsExhausted());Console.WriteLine(rs.IsFullyFetched);Console.WriteLine(rs.PagingState);` which is suggesting no more data is left.

Comment: I asked three questions - you really only answered one.. and the way you answered it raises a concern.  I don't know how relevant this concern is to your issue, but `statement.SetAutoPage(false);statement.SetPageSize(1000);` should be expressed as `var newStatement = statement.SetAutoPage(false).SetPageSize(1000);`.  the methods should not be thought as mutating `statement`, or the instance of `IStatement`;  it should be thought as creating \ returning a new IStatement instance.

Comment: @brett the same code first started working .  I am not sure how. In between I changed the consistency level to ALL in query. And run it few time with failure. I also changed some setting of queries. And when I checked letter it started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

by default the fetchsize is set to 5000 to shield an application against accidentally retrieving large result sets in a single response, maybe u can play with .setFetchSize(int) property

Comment: I don't think there any such method in C#, can you refer some link out put some code.

Comment: "[shielding] an application against accidentally retrieving large result sets"... where are you getting this 'odd' reasoning and information? most of what I've read on this matter doesn't portray reasonings for defaults (they seem to be in the context of the drivers, not server or native).  If they weren't specified, the number of rows in the result set would vary based on operation timeout.  I would expect the actual reasoning of a default LIMIT to be more about consistency with respect to fairly high latency operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know that the C# driver has [paging enabled by default](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.13/html/P_Cassandra_Statement_AutoPage.htm)  (`AutoPage = true`) and the [default page size is 5000](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.13/html/F_Cassandra_QueryOptions_DefaultPageSize.htm) (`DefaultPageSize = 5000`).

I think the problem with your test is that you are using the `RowSet.IsFullyFetched` property as the condition in the loop:

```
while (!rs.IsFullyFetched)
{
    ...
}
```

Try replacing it with the `RowSet.IsExhausted()` method instead:

```
while (!rs.IsExhausted())
{
    rs.FetchMoreResults();
    foreach (var row in rs)
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

`RowSet.IsExhausted()` returns true/false depending on whether there are more results similar to `IsFullyFetched` but with the difference that it will page for more results. Cheers!